# htaccess works but content doesn't load

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, loading

When I use index.php?id=this-is-an-article the page loads with the content, when I use /articles/this-is-an-article the page loads without any content, any idea as to how I can resolve this?

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force www. in all requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.net/$1 [L,R=301]

# enable hiding php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?p=$1  

# index.php?id=this-is-an-article => /articles/this-is-an-article 
RewriteRule /articles/(.*)  index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do some debug output for startes: `<pre><?PHP print_r($_GET); ?></pre>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the leading slash. It's also best practice to begin a regex like that with ^ and end it with $.

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$  index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: And for the debug output I'm getting this...

Array ( [id] => this-is-an-article.php/this-is-an-article ) And that's not what I want.. because it's not a .php file, it should be pulling from the database.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. It was the hiding of the php extension that stuffed it up.